# Matt. 13:8 - "the good soil", Why different yields from "the good soil,"and what is the implications?

Tags: matthew, parables

The sower  is **one** (ὁ σπείρων), and he sowed  "seeds" that have same yield potential on **same** **good soild**.

- Were the yields - 100, 60 & 30 folds to the sower's expectation, or to the potential of the field?
- Does **ἀκουέτω** (v9) (let him hear! - an imperative), imply possible relation of the yield to the **field**?
- And, was the "good soil" a good soil by origin?

Text: Matt. 13:8 (YLT)

"and others fell upon **the good ground**, and were giving fruit, **some indeed a hundredfold, and some sixty, and some thirty."**

Comment: could you clarify this question - it is not clear what you are asking.  Are you asking about predestination or Calvinism, or what?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of the yields in the parable of the Sower?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/28746/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-yields-in-the-parable-of-the-sower)

Comment: My question is to find Scriptural answer why different yields from the same"good soil and  seed," that we may all go for higher yields.  The answer should come from the Scripture, not filtered through one's doctrinal presuppositions. The Scripture is the final authority I will submit to.

Comment: @SirAthos. It does not answer my question. Because, for example, God blessed Isaac to have 100 folds of "what he sowed" (by implication).  But the 100, 60, and 30-fold yields resulted from the same "good soil"  and the same amount "seed."  If it were not from equal "starting", the measurements would be meaningless.